# Center Align in interface builder in both iPhone 5 and iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, user-interface

In XCode interface builder : I have some images in my view that I need them to be center aligned vertically.
But screen height of Retina 4 and Retina 3.5 differs and I don't like to use OS6 for relative coordinates.
Is there anyway to do this is interface builder or I should write some code?

Comment: Have you tried autoresizing from IB?

Answer (score 6):

Using Autolayout in interface builder, select your view, choose the constraints menu in the bottom right of the canvas, and choose center vertically in container. This will apply to both screen sizes.

Comment: I thought Autolayout was only available for IOS6?

Comment: It is, but this question refers to the iPhone 5, which only runs ios6. Any new iPhone apps should really target ios6 and above only.

Comment: But I need the app to run on OS>=5

Answer (score 5):

You should probably use actual code for this.

Luckily, it's fairly straightforward: just obtain the screen height, subtract the image height, and divide by two.

```
CGFloat height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
CGRect frame = [imageView frame];
frame.origin.y = (height-frame.size.height)/2;
[imageView setFrame:frame];
```

Comment: This is both right (the code would work) and wrong (you don't need it, and it would be easier to programmatically create a centring constraint than do frame arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoresizing(IB->Size inspector) for it. But you will not see autoresizing options if auto layout is set for xib. You have to remove auto layout(IB->File inspector) first & then set autoresizing properties as you want.

Comment: Autolayout can do it much easier. There are specific constraints to center views in their containers.